# Building a multi module maven project with Skaffold and Jib

Tags: maven, skaffold, jib

Is it possible to build a multi module maven project with skaffold and jib builder?

My project structure:

```
my-project-parent-module
- my-project-main-module
- my-project-lib-module
```

`my-project-main-module` contains the Main class, and has the jib plugin configured, and has a dependency on `my-project-lib-module`.
The `lib-module` doesn't have jib configured, because no image is needed.

The documentation has [an example](https://skaffold.dev/docs/pipeline-stages/builders/jib/#jib-maven-and-gradle-locally) of a multimodule skaffold:

```yaml
build:
  artifacts:
  - image: image1 # jib artifact
    jib:
      fromImage: image2
    requires:
    - image: image2
  - image: image2 # base image artifact
```

But this is a different scenario, because both modules produce an image (via jib).

Below is one of the skaffold configurations I tried:

```yaml
apiVersion: skaffold/v2beta29
kind: Config
metadata:
  name: my-project
build:
  local:
    push: false
  artifacts:
    - image: my-image-name
      context: ./
      jib:
        project: com.example:my-project-main-module
  ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you specify a `project:`, Skaffold will invoke something like:

```
mvn --projects com.example:my-project-main-module --also-make jib:build
```

This will be executed from the context directory.  The `--also-make` causes Maven to rebuild any dependencies (like your `lib-module`) as necessary.

Make sure you can run the command-line above separately from Skaffold.  Check that your `lib-module` is included as a `<module>` in your top-level `pom.xml`, and that your `main-module` has a `<dependency>` to your `lib-module`.

Comment: Thank you, this worked. The problem that I had was that I added the jib plugin to the `my-project-main-module`. I needed to add it in the parent module.